# How to use different tsconfig file for tests?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

in my project I use 2 different tsconfig files

- `tsconfig.json`
- `tsconfig.specs.json` - for testing

how can I tell Intellij Idea to use both?
i.e. In `Settings` - `Langauges & Frameworks` - `TypeScript` I can switch between different `Compile scope`s, but the `Options` are not per compile scope (but only once per project).

Notes:

- I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 18.2.5
- I found a related issue [WEB-15538: TypeScript WebStorm 10 EAP: Scope & by module configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15538)- but maybe this was only fixed for WebStorm - not in Idea Ultimate?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think we only need to register the file-types:

In *Settings* | *Editor* | *File Types* > *TypeScript Config* add your custom tsconfig file names, e.g.

- `tsconfig.app.json`
- `tsconfig.lib.json`
- `tsconfig.spec.json`
- etc.

[image]

With these settings in place:

- IntelliJ should show syntax highlighting and completion suggestions in your tsconfig files
- the IntelliJ typescript service should recognize all these tsconfig files and compile everything:
  i.e. it is important that you use [include/exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples) in each of the tsconfig files, so that only the relevant files are compiled