# How to use different tsconfig file for test files in vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

This question is similar to this question: [How to use different tsconfig file for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890331/how-to-use-different-tsconfig-file-for-tests) But I am asking for visual studio code.

I have two `tsconfig` files:

- `tsconfig.json` for all application files
- `tsconfig.test.json` for all test files

`tsconfig.json` excludes all `*.spec.ts` while `tsconfig.test.json` only includes these files.

How can I make visual studio code to understand that an opened `.spec.ts` file belongs to `tsconfig.test.json`?

I dont want to separate all my tests into an own `test` directory with its own `tsconfig.json` included but rather keep them next to the application files.

Comment: For anyone looking for the opposite layout with tests in a separate folder, please see this useful answer on how to make VSCode work properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153019/3082178.

Comment: Since TS 3.0 there are "project references" that solve this exact problem. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VS Code has limitation to a single `tsconfig.json` for now (see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463).

Considering the project structure is:

- src/
- tsconfig.json
- tsconfig.test.json

Create `./src/tsconfig.json` file with content:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.test.json"
}
```

Comment: Does this mean files that are not tests within src/ will use the src/tsconfig.json ?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, in my experience, it does. This means that VS Code will report that "File is not part of a Typescript project."

Comment: This is unhelpful, this imports all your test config into your main config. Which defeats the object of having a test config at all

Comment: No, tsconfig.json and src/tsconfig.json are different files