# "Error: Cannot find module '@modules/user'" for multiple tsconfig file under project in typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

how to set up eslint for different eslintrc and tsconfig in typescript
I have following structure and test command for compile eslint. Whenever I run `tsc`, it generated all error from file using path alias under test but from editor (webstorm/vscode) path are correct without error. How can I configure so when I run compilt command it can read different tsconfig.json not just from `root/tsconfig.json`.

```
- root
    |_tsconfig.json
    |_.eslintrc.json
    |_test
        |_tsconfig.json
        |_.eslintrc.json
        |_abc



# root/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "@uc/eslint-config-react",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
}

# root/test/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "chai"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@abc/*": ["./abc/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044697/how-to-use-different-tsconfig-file-for-test-files-in-vscode